# How to disable form submit while it is waiting for a server response in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a form

```
<form method="POST" id="form1" action"<%=login%>">
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="Log in" />
```

where the %=login% is a jsp page that calls to java code.

I've noticed that if I hold down the enter button when logging in or press the button many times it continually creates new sessions and requests for the user. What is the best way for me to disable the ability to continually press the button while I'm waiting for a server response?

Thanks

Comment: what is stopping you from hiding or disabling the button?

Comment: What is a good way to disable the button until I hear back from a server? I tried adding an 'onclick' function to the button where it disables it and then submits, but the button is disabled so it is not submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd call the JSP page with an AJAX request. To prevent the page from reloading add an EventListener to your form:

```
document.getElementById("form1").AddEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    // AJAX Request
});
```

If the request succeeds or fails, set the disabled-attribute of the button to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the action if you detect it more than once

```
document.querySelector("#form1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  if (this.dataset.active) {
    e.preventDefault;
    return;
  }
  this.dataset.active = 'true';
});
```